# Display custom error message in MVC view with PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, error-handling

I need to display user friendly error message in the view I am in, and wondering what will be the best solution. I can display and error page using error controller but this is not what i want to achieve. I need to handle all custom error messages in any model and display an error in the view you are in. For example:

I am in  "user"  controller. When creating new user, the PHP model code checks if same user name exist, if exist I want to display a message in the view  or maybe  have something like this in header: `echo $error;` which  display any error message I have set to be displayed from  any model if occurred.

Example error message in model:

```
 if ($p0 > 0) {
        $IsValid = false;
        log::LOG_USER_ERROR("This user already exist!", $username);
        exit("This user already exist! </br> ");
    }
```

This code write the error in a log file successfully, however how do I display the error message in the same view I am in? `exit()` displays the message in a blank page. I need to display it as block in red in the same view and design.

Comment: Don't call static methods from your model, it will be a right pain to test. And definitely don't exit there either, that will make it even harder to test. It's OK to return an error condition, and then to do something with it in your controller. It sounds like you could render this in your layout (the common template that wraps all of your page templates).

Comment: yes halfer this is the correct way just cant figure it out how to implement it. I did try to return false in the model and then  get the false returned in the controller somehow. From the controller is easy to show message in the view but just cant figure it out. Is there any examples?  thanks

Comment: Currently this is a bit broad, and it's hard to answer without knowing the structure of your whole framework. I think your best bet would be to look at a popular MVC-like framework and work through their examples. You'll then be able to use their structure applied to your own framework. Maybe Laravel, Slim or Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

exit() terminates the current script, so the code for your View is not executed.

Instead, part of your View should be an area to display messages. Then you can put the error message in a variable (probably an array of messages) that the View displays to the user in that area.

Comment: hi bobbye, I have added exit() just to check if the statement execute. I like to replace the exit()  with some sort of a  function to return false condition to the controller and then from the controller to render the  message in the view